# Update UI from a bound foregroundservice

Tags: android, service, udp

Since I am quite new to developing an Android app I would like to ask the more experienced developers how to approach the following problem.

The app that I am trying to build is supposed to do the following:
When the app is running it is constantly receiving various doubles via `upd` packages. Depending on the double values it will show certain messages in text- and image views on the main activity.

So far I already set up a foreground service (running on an extra thread) which is receiving the doubles. The service is bound to the main activity. 
I decided to use a bound service because in future I would like to connect additional activities to that service.

And here are my questions:

1. Did I choose the right config (bound foreground service) for what I am planing to do?
2. How can I update my image- and text views depending on the values of the doubles received by the udp service? Can I do this direclty inside the service and only push an update if the values changed?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

> Did I choose the right config (bound foreground service) for what I am planing to do?

No objections to the bound `Service`. Having an interested `Activity` bind to the `Service` will ensure it's being kept alive as long as the `Activity` is considered to be in the foreground.

> How can I update my image- and text views depending on the values of the doubles received by the udp service? Can I do this directy inside the service and only push an update if the values changed?

You should not try to update a `View` "from outside". Only the component (`Activity` or `Fragment`) to which the `View` is belonging should have the right to modify it.

Instead, just notify interested components of changes in the data.

Ideas for intra-app communication:

- You could send broadcasts via [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager)
- Or you have the `Service` update a data repository and use `LiveData` to keep the UI up to date like described in the [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) .

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will give this a try.